# SQL Query in Laravel is not returning the correct result

Tags: sql, laravel

I am trying to get the expired listings based on the availability periods, there are 3 different available periods. a row should only be returned if the latest not null to_date_* for that row is before now.

A sample data:

| id | from_date_1 | to_date_1 | from_date_2 | to_date_2 | from_date_3 | to_date_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-06-10 | 2021-08-15 | 2021-08-16 | 2021-08-31 | 2021-09-01 | 2021-09-15 |
| 2 | 2021-06-25 | 2021-08-10 | 2021-08-11 | 2021-08-25 | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | 2021-06-25 | 2021-08-20 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

My SQL Query is:

```
$listings = collect();
            $all_listings = Listing::query()
                        ->where('vendor_id', $vendor->id)
                        ->where('is_deleted', 0)
                        ->where('is_published', 1)
                        ->where('is_approved', 1)
                        ->where('lease_term', '!=', 'long_term')
                        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                        ->paginate(10);

            foreach($all_listings as $lis)
            {
                if($lis->to_date_3 != null && ($lis->to_date_3 < \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')))
                {
                    $listings->add($lis);
                    continue;
                }
                elseif($lis->to_date_2 != null && ($lis->to_date_2 < \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')))
                {
                    $listings->add($lis);
                    continue;
                }
                elseif($lis->to_date_1 < \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'))
                {
                    $listings->add($lis);
                    
                }
            }
```

The result should be:

| id | from_date_1 | to_date_1 | from_date_2 | to_date_2 | from_date_3 | to_date_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2021-06-25 | 2021-08-20 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

However, the query is returning all the 3 listings. how can I fix the query to get the correct result?

Comment: so you want to achive this via query without for each is it

Comment: no I am ok with using foreach, the most important is to get the right result as I provided. thank you

Comment: sorry im bit unclear about the question

Comment: @OsamaShaki it's not really clear what the problem is. Nipun has a point, i don't think the foreach is a good way of handeling this. Instead of making a new collection you can put your if statements in your view, where you display the table, or you can edit your select to only get what you really need. Changing the query is the best way.

Comment: ok Gert B, do you have any suggestion to amend the query in the controller, I don't want to send so many records to the view and then compare it there.

Comment: @NipunTharuksha get the expired listings based on the availability periods, as user might not provide the 3 periods, period 1 is a must. Thank you

Comment: @OsamaShaki For me it's not really clear what the correct data is. So it's very hard to help you with the query. I agree on not overcomplicating the view.

Comment: Try ->whereNotNull('to_date_2') for achive......$data = Listing::whereNotNull('from_date_2')->where(function($request){
                $request->orWhere('to_date_3','<',date('Y-m-d'));
                $request->orWhere('to_date_2','<',date('Y-m-d'));
                $request->orWhere('to_date_1','<',date('Y-m-d'));
        })->get();

Comment: Not a ideal solution..

Comment: ok thank you I will try

Comment: These query will help you to avoid foreach loop after getting data

Comment: Why wouldn't the 3rd example be classed as expired?

Comment: @RahulJat maybe it's better to add this as an answer, so it's easier to read, and explain what you did. It could be the solution. i would suggest changing the name of `$request` because it is a query, not a request

Comment: @Rwd I have updated the sample result, 3rd example should be returned only.

Comment: Ok, just to be sure, a row should only be returned if the **latest** not null `to_date_*` for that row is before now or should it be if **any** of the not null `to_date_*`s for that row are before now?

Comment: if the latest one is not null. if to_date_3 is not null and is before now. the result should have this row. thank you for the help

Comment: Hi Rwd, any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recreated your db and tested below code with above data.No need to use `fooreach` then Check this

**Migration**

```
 $table->dateTime('from_date_1');
            $table->dateTime('to_date_1');
            $table->dateTime('from_date_2')->nullable();
            $table->dateTime('to_date_2')->nullable();
            $table->dateTime('from_date_3')->nullable();
            $table->dateTime('to_date_3')->nullable();
```

**DB**

[image]

**Query**

```
$data = Listing::where(function($query){
            $query->whereDate('to_date_1', '>=', Carbon::now())
                ->orWhereDate('to_date_2', '>=', Carbon::now())
                ->orWhereDate('to_date_3', '>=', Carbon::now());
        })->get();
```

**Result**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "from_date_1": "2021-06-10 00:00:00",
    "to_date_1": "2021-08-15 00:00:00",
    "from_date_2": "2021-08-16 00:00:00",
    "to_date_2": "2021-08-31 00:00:00",
    "from_date_3": "2021-09-01 00:00:00",
    "to_date_3": "2021-09-15 00:00:00",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "from_date_1": "2021-06-25 00:00:00",
    "to_date_1": "2021-08-10 00:00:00",
    "from_date_2": "2021-08-11 00:00:00",
    "to_date_2": "2021-08-25 00:00:00",
    "from_date_3": null,
    "to_date_3": null,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
  }
]
```

**Efficiency**

[image]

**Update**

> Since required answer has been amended later my answer I have updated
> the query as follow

```
$to_date_3 = Listing::whereNotNull('to_date_1')->whereNotNull('to_date_2')->whereDate('to_date_3', '<=', Carbon::now())->get();
$to_date_2 = Listing::whereNull('to_date_3')->whereNotNull('to_date_2')->whereDate('to_date_2', '<=', Carbon::now())->get();
$to_date_1 = Listing::whereNull('to_date_3')->whereNull('to_date_2')->whereDate('to_date_1', '<=', Carbon::now())->get();

$result = $to_date_1->merge($to_date_2)->merge($to_date_3);
```

**Result**

```
[
  {
    "id": 3,
    "from_date_1": "2021-06-25 00:00:00",
    "to_date_1": "2021-08-20 00:00:00",
    "from_date_2": null,
    "to_date_2": null,
    "from_date_3": null,
    "to_date_3": null,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
  }
]
```

**Efficiency**

[image]

Comment: Nipun, I should get only the 3rd row from the sample data. not record 1&2... you can refer to the result sample. thank you

Comment: yes I only amend the result. a row should only be returned if the latest not null to_date_* for that row is before now. hope it is clear now. thanks alot

Comment: Hi @Nipun, could you update the query to get the sample result please? Thanks

Comment: @OsamaShaki please check

Comment: Thanks a lot Nipun, Appreciate your help